# How do you log out with the new header?

Tags: support

Previously when we hovered over our username we got a popup with a link to log out. Apparently the popup has gone, and I don't see how to log out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to search for it too, but it's under the "StackExchange" pulldown.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to say that the placement makes sense to me, though :/

Comment: @radagast going to SE sites, your login and such are all part of SE system, so they put it under SE. I sorta get it